# What talismans bring good luck in different folklore?

Tags: magic

We all know of the four-leafed clover and the horseshoe - now I wonder what other items are considered magical in various cultures - as in bringing good luck to the owner.

Comment: If you rephrase this question, "talisman" will be a good term to use.

Comment: A [rabbit's foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit%27s_foot). And Wikipedia has full categories on [lucky symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lucky_symbols) and [talismans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Talismans)